# How to serve image from my server with a MERN stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Broad overview of my app: Users can submit posts with images and text.

I am using MERN stack.

Currently, images are being saved into my `localhost:3001` server at `/public/uploads/<images>` and the route is then saved into my database.

I am now trying to render the posts of screen.

```
// example value of what gets stored into my db
// post.img.url = "public\uploads\user-5cc37dda4142ff49a8c903d2-1557200552890.png"

posts.map( ( post, i ) => {
  return <img src={ post.img.url } alt='post image'} />
} )
```

When I hover over the chrome console to view the route that it returns, this is the route that shows up: 
`http://localhost:3000/profile/admin/posts/public/uploads/user-5cc37dda4142ff49a8c903d2-1557174873119.png`

To actually view the image, you would have to go to this route: `http://localhost:3001/uploads/user-5cc37dda4142ff49a8c903d2-1557200552890.png`

How can I get the correct route for my images?

Some addition details that might matter

```
// this line is in my server.js
app.use( express.static( path.join( __dirname, 'public' ) ) )
```

Comment: One important thing to note here is that you are mounting the `public` folder to the '/' route implicitly. That means all public urls should just omit the "public" string from the url.

Comment: Your image url have back-slashes \, is that a typo or that's how it's actually saved? no-escaping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set some global or .env variable in your React app which contain a http route to your server like this: `SERVER_HOST = 'http://localhost:3001'`. Then you need to store the relative path to your images in database like `/uploads/user-*.png`. Now you can get access to images like this:

```
posts.map( ( post, i ) => {
  return <img src={ SERVER_HOST + post.img.path } alt='post image'} />
})
```